# Why does this code not load webform submissions?

Tags: webforms

I’m trying to load all submissions from a specific webform, and for some reason it always returns no results (even though I know it has results from the UI). [I found this bit of code](https://www.codimth.com/blog/web/drupal/how-load-programmatically-webform-submissions-drupal-8) that I adapted for my needs:

```php
$webform = \Drupal\webform\Entity\Webform::load($webform_id);

if ($webform->hasSubmissions()) {
  $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('webform_submission')
    ->condition('webform_id',  $webform_id);
  $result = $query->execute();
  $submission_data = [];
  foreach ($result as $item) {
    $submission = \Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformSubmission::load($item);
    $submission_data[] = $submission->getData();
  }
}
```

However for some reason the **results are always an empty array**, even if the `$webform->hasSubmissions()` returns `true` . Not sure why this code isn’t working? Seems simple enough?

Comment: WebformSubmission::load expects an identifier. What is the data type of $item?

Comment: Good question, but it's not even getting there as `$result = $query->execute();` returns an empty array, even though I have forms results.

Comment: Where is the code executed, or more to the point in the context of what user account? Entity queries are access-sensitive

Comment: Code is executed in a custom service that I created

Comment: Is the webform ID correct? It seems like this is becoming an interview...

Comment: The form ID is indeed correct, as the `$webform = \Drupal\webform\Entity\Webform::load($webform_id);` line returns the webform object when I debug it. I appreciate the follow up.

Comment: How is the service consumed? Is it a route? Form submission? Cron job? If the latter you'll need `->accessCheck(FALSE)` on the query. If you're executing in the context of a user session where the account doesn't have permissions to view the entities you're loading, you'll need the same thing

Comment: @Clive `->accessCheck(FALSE)` worked!!

Comment: Not specifying an accessCheck is deprecated in Drupal 9: https://www.drupal.org/node/3201242